# Error when attempting to save and build a .tex-file with Atom

Tags: errors

I don't know how to copy the error message so here's an image instead! Any help is appreciated. 
[image]

Edit: Strawberry Perl is installed. MiKTeX and Latex Package for Atom installed. Using Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome. Remove the diacritics in your file e.g. using [this tool](https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/) and try again.

Comment: Or try to save the file using a different filename and then try again.